# Is it possible to restore index from 2.3.2 elasticsearch to 5.4.1 eleasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have more properties in 2.3.2 elastic search version. Now i am using 5.4.1. I have to use same index and properties in that version. Is it possible to restore the index and properties in simple way .

Comment: Can anyone update on this?. Is the feature available or not?

Answer (score 0):

If you are migrating from version 2.3.2 to 5.4.1 you can definitely use the indices created in version 2.x, provided that no index was created in version 1.x.
Similarly while upgrading from 5.x. to 6.x. you have to make sure no index was created in version 2.x. or before, else you have to reindex
Have a look at this link:
[link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/reindex-upgrade.html)

Comment: but i have used different machine. 2.x installed in one VM and 5.x installed in local machine. how to copy the index and properties from one machine to another machine ?. Can you please provide a sample code for this scenario?

Comment: yes , i created index through sense addon in chrome

Comment: yes, i follwed. When i give input and output in elasticdump, it throws input undefined, output undefined. How to resolve this?

Comment: Please don't ask such stuff as "how to resolve this error". Debugging you have to do on your own. StackOverflow is not meant for this

Comment: i just asked a suggestion only.Because i am new for elasticsearch. I think StackOverflow give the solution for everything. No one replied like that